# How to create complex directories on Grails

Tags: grails

I was wondering if Grails (version 2.4.4) support nested directories, for example:

1. `localhost:8080/project/accounts/index`
2. `localhost:8080/project/accounts/settings`
3. `localhost:8080/project/accounts/settings/advance`
4. `localhost:8080/project/accounts/settings/summary`

The first two can be easily made by creating a controller named `AccountsController` with methods `index()` and `settings()`. But how about the third and fourth? I'm thinking of organizing my projects on this fashion, against the default `project/controller/action` way on how Grails creates directories. Does it need to configure complex settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With URL mappings. http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings.

Grails doesn't create directories.